# Getting web scraped data for text classification using svm

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, svm

I am going to get text data from the web to create a text classification model using svm. After training and testing the model, the model should understand each text category automatically.

After web scraping, the data will be stored in json format.

I am using a supervised learning algorithm, so labelling should be in a json file for each text category. I can do it manually, but my problem is whether I put all categories of data in a single file or separate files for each text category?

I am asking this because I am using this text data for model training and testing. I want to get understand why we create separate files for each text category?
I try to get past web data using php and  python scraping. But It was not success. Without using a API, Is there a method to get past web data?

Comment: Why do you think we need to " create separate files for each text category"?

Comment: Yes, I understood after reading more research papers. No need to create separate files before classifying text data. After the classifying I need to create separate files for each category. Am I correct? Thanks for the support Jack Fleeting.